# Read HTTP request data in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, server, httpserver

I am trying to write a basic "echo" HTTP server that writes back the raw data it receives in the request. How can I get the request data as a string?

This is my program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler


class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  def do_GET(self):
    print('data', self.rfile.readall())
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    self.end_headers()
    message = 'Hello Client!'
    self.wfile.write(bytes(message, 'utf8'))
    return

def server_start():
  address = ('', 1992)
  httpd = HTTPServer(address, RequestHandler)
  httpd.serve_forever()


server_start()
```

Error:

```
self.rfile.readall(): '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'readall'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a get request there won't be a `body`, so the data is going to be sent in the `url`.

```py
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import urlparse

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        parsed_path = urlparse.urlparse(self.path)
        print(parsed_path.query)
        ...
```

Otherwise, you should implement a `POST` method if you want to send any more complex object as data (take a look at different [HTTP methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) if you're not familiar with them).

A post method would be something like:

```py
def do_POST(self):
    post_body = self.rfile.readall()
```

Note that here you **can** use the method `rfile.readall()`. Here you have a nice [gist](https://gist.github.com/trungly/5889154) with some examples!

Comment: The gist works great! I was trying to read a known length of bytes like `self.rfile.read(5)` in `do_GET()` but it just stuck. It appears `do_GET()` doesn't support any read. I tried `self.rfile.readall()` in `do_POST()` and it didn't work, same error as above. Thanks for the `Content-Length` method.